# Sufficient condition for isotone functions $f$ and $g$ mapping between chain $X$ and $Y$ to be equal i.e., $f= g$.

Tags: order-theory

> 11 Theorem *Let $f$ and $g$ be isotone functions from a chain $X$ to a chain $Y,$ let $X_0$ be a subset of $X$ on which $f$ and $g$ agree, and let $Y_0$ be $f[X_0]$. A sufficient condition that $f= g$ is that $Y_0$ intersects every set of the form $\{y: u\lt y\lt v, ~u\ne y ~~\textrm{and}~~ y \ne v\},$ where $u$ and $v$ are members of $Y$ such that $u\lt v.$*
>
> **Proof** If $f\ne g,$ then $f(x) \ne g(x)$ for some $x$ in $X,$ and we may suppose that $f(x)\lt g(x)$. Each point of $X_0$ which is **less than or equal to $x$ maps under $f$ to a point less than or equal to $f(x)$**, because $f$ is isotone, and **each point which is greater than or equal to $x$ maps under $g$ into a point greater than or equal to $g(x)$**, because $g$ is isotone. **It follows that no point of $X_0$ maps into the set $\{y: f(x)\lt y\lt g(x), f(x)\ne y~~\textrm{and}~~y \ne g(x)\}$**, and the theorem is proved.

The excerpt is taken from *Orderings* in *General Topology* by *John Kelley*.

I'm not comprehending the bold statements above in the excerpt.

At the first sight, I can conclude that the proof is using the method of contradiction.

What is the point of taking in consideration the function $g$ when the points $\geq x\in X_0\,?$ I'am simply not getting that.

How did Kelley conclude then that $X_0$ doesn't map to $\{y: f(x)\lt y\lt g(x) \}\,?$

I'm failing to visualise that how it proves $Y_0= f[X_0]$ intersects with $\{y: u\lt y\lt v\}.$

Answer (score 2):

About the first two bold statements, I think they already have the explanation there (because $f$ and $g$ are isotone). Perhaps you overlooked something here...

For the final part, let $z \in X_0$ and suppose $$f(x) < f(z) = g(z) < g(x).$$
Then it must be $x < z$, because $X$ is a chain.
But then $g(z) < f(x)$ is in contradiction with the isotonicity of $g$.

So there is no $z \in X_0$ such that $$f(x) < f(z) < g(x),$$ or equivalently,
there is no $y$ in the image of $X_0$ by $f$ (or $g$, which is the same) such that 
$$f(x) < y < g(x)$$
and this is certainly the case if $f(X_0) = g(X_0) = Y_0$ every open interval of the chain.

Comment: Firstly, thanks @amrsa for the answer. Could you tell me whether $f(z)= \color{red}{g(x)}\lt g(x)$ is a typo or not? I mean why did you write $f(z) = g(x)$ and not $f(z)= g(z)\,?$ The former gives $g(x)\lt g(x)$ which seems awkward to me. Anyways, I'll comment if there is more query regarding the post :)

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Of course it was a typo :) Corrected. I mean, if $z \in X_0$, then $f(z) = g(z)$; but then we have a contradiction, because either $x < z$ and $g(z) < g(x)$ or $z < x$ and $f(x) < f(z)$. Thanks for bringing my attention to this.